# Deleting a list item in a content editable list is causing damage to my dom

Tags: javascript, html, list, internet-explorer-11

My initial code:

```
<div>
<ul id="UL1" contenteditable="true">
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

if I delete the list item or I create a new list item by creating enter and then hit enter again, the list becomes uneditable, and it clobbers my DOM (saved through javascript):

```
<div>
</div><ul id="UL1">
<li>Test</li><li>Best</li></ul><p><br /></p><ul>
</ul><div>
</div>
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet to reproduce the problem? Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS I have provided a working snippet. If you can't reproduce, is this maybe a bug just in IE 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this using the following:

1. Capture the clicked on list item in the click event, using Event.target. The target for this event *is* the list item. I store this into a variable (ie `myPackage.currentLI = e.target`)
2. Add a key listener to my OLs/ULs and track keys up, down and enter, and adjust `myPackage.currentLI` using `.nextSibling` and `.previousSibling`
3. In the same key listener, detect the conditions (enter, backspace from LI with no content) and call `preventDefault` on the event

Comment: This isn't of much use to anyone without providing the relevant `javascript` hence me asking for a working snippet to reproduce the problem.